# UITextView missing text at the end?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

[image]

So the white background part is a UITextView and the blue bubble is a UIImageView. How come the UITextView lost some text at the end when given the same text at different row of the tableview?

Here’s how I configured the UITextView:

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
//self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.textView.editable = NO;
self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

I need the selection and copy capabilities of UITextView, so I can’t use UILabel. Basically, I want to make UITextView behaves like UILabel.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1:

This is how I set the constraints:

```
[self.textView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
               make.edges.equalTo(self.msgContainerView).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(kPaddingTB, kPadding, kPaddingTB, kPadding))
            }];
```

Edit 2:

It seems that the text disappears when tableview is scrolled.

Comment: How you set constraint

Comment: @ManishMahajan Please see the edit 1 I just added. Thank you.

Comment: @Evan **For Edit 2:** If `textView` is added on `tableView` you will have to manage the `text` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method too as it refreshes the cell and its content whenever you scroll the table.

Comment: @TheTiger I know that and the text do change in response to scrolling and the text content is correct too. The problem is the text got trimmed when displayed in textview as showed in the image above.

Comment: @Evan Text can not be trimmed until you do it manually. Either text went in next line or the `textView` has the text you see. By changing the frame or constraint text can not be change.

Comment: @TheTiger That’s the weird part, the text shows up fully some time and missing some text other time. I have tried changing the frame but didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: @Evan Did you scroll the `textView` and check if it has full text?

Comment: @TheTiger Well, the textview is not scrollable but I did use the view debug to inspect it and it has the full text.

Comment: @Evan So probably content size of textView is not correct. Somehow it is less so that you can not scroll.

Comment: @TheTiger No, it’s not scrollable because I set scrollable to NO, see the description above.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the textView height based on text and set it to textView? Make textView edge insets 0 for all sides.